# Why can't I clean reactive data (upload) and use it multiple times throughout other functions that return plots, tables, etc?

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny

Initially, I was basically just repeating `req(input$file1) inFile <- input$file1` every single time I was producing an output so I got tired of repeating myself and realized I can use a reactive. However, after creating this code below, I always get errors saying either `Warning: Error in read_excel: unused arguments (header = input$header, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)` or `Error in :` path `must be a string`. An example of some code I am trying to implement it in is below the code example.

```
data_step1 <- reactive({ 
      inFile <- input$file1
      if(!is.null(inFile)) {
        return(NULL)
      }
      raw_data <- read_excel(inFile$datapath, header = input$header, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
      raw_data
        
    }) # EndDataReactive

    cleaned_data <- reactive({
      # Reads Excel File Input / Cleans Raw Data
            col_names <- array(read_excel(data_step1(), sheet = 1, n_max = 1, col_names = FALSE))
            rawdata <- data.frame(read_excel(data_step1(), sheet = 1, skip = 3, col_names = FALSE))
            colnames(rawdata) <- col_names
            
            convert_data1 <- rawdata
            
            wbb1 <- convert_data1 %>% select(11:36) # The Dataframe that includes all of the key variables required for data manipulation.

            # Graph Processing with Cleaned Data
            
            wbb1$VO2 <- (wbb1$VO2)/1000   #CONVERT TO LITERS
            wbb1$VO2 <- as.numeric(wbb1$VO2)  
            wbb1$VCO2 <- (wbb1$VCO2)/1000   #CONVERT TO LITERS
            wbb1$VCO2 <- as.numeric(wbb1$VCO2)

            wbb1
    })
```

**Example Implementation**

```
output$output4 <- renderText({
        watts.vo2.lm <- lm(wbb1$Power ~ wbb1$VO2, data = cleaned_data())
        summary(watts.vo2.lm)$r.squared
        cleaned_data()
        
    }) #EndRenderText
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Any help would be lovely.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should reverse the conditions, `return` `NULL` when `inFile` is  `NULL`.

```
data_step1 <- reactive({ 
  inFile <- input$file1
  if(is.null(inFile)) {
    return(NULL)
  }
  raw_data <- readxl::read_excel(inFile$datapath, header = input$header, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
  raw_data
  
})
```

Using `req` must be shorter

```
data_step1 <- reactive({ 
  req(input$file1)
  raw_data <- readxl::read_excel(input$file1$datapath, header = input$header, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
  raw_data
})
```